# How to install dkim for postfix in centos 5.4

Tags: centos, postfix, dkim

I am trying to install DKIM for my postfix so that i have a signature. I am following this guide: http://allaboutlamp.com/2009/09/setup-dkim-for-postfix-in-fedora-using-dkim-milter/

But how do i create a DNS record for TXT ? Where is the file. My originaldomain.com is running in a hosted server, where i dont have terminal access. And i have another server where i am trying to install this setup. Which is only for outgoing emails for newsletters.

```
Step 1:
[root@out tmp]# openssl genrsa -out rsa.private 1024
[root@out tmp]# openssl rsa -in rsa.private -out rsa.public -pubout -outform PEM
[root@out tmp]# ls
rsa.private  rsa.public

Step 2: How can i know assign dkim postfix signatures?
[root@out tmp]# yum list dkim-milter
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: ftp.heanet.ie
 * base: ftp.heanet.ie
 * epel: ftp.heanet.ie
 * extras: ftp.heanet.ie
 * ius: mirror.rackspace.com
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
Installed Packages
dkim-milter.x86_64                                                                                     2.8.3-4.el5                                                                                      installed
[root@out tmp]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had good success using DKIMProxy. Check out this article: http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/getting-dkimproxy-installed-and-configured

And in your comments to @mattdm you are confusing SPF with DKIM-Signature. Both use DNS TXT records but they are separate things/records. With some Registrars/DNS Providers you need to turn on "Advanced DNS Records" or similar description in order to create TXT records.

You basically publish the public part of your key in the TXT record for DKIM-Signature.

HTH

Cheers

Comment: For my domain provider, how can i add out.example.com   to achieve this according to your guide ? ex: "create mail._domainkey.domain.tld with the contents of domain.tld.pub. Your public key will span at least two lines, so combine all of the lines of the key together when putting it in your DNS record. The whole DNS record will look something like this:

k=rsa; t=s; p=MFwwDQYJ......0JMCAwEAAQ=="

Comment: When you create a TXT record you provide selector._domainkey.example.com as the Host and k,t & p parameter/values as the Text Record. _domainkey is not a variable, that is what should be in the value for the Host part. selector is a variable and is usually default or mail or whatever you chose as the selector. HTH

Answer (score 0):

> But how do i create a DNS record for
>   TXT ? Where is the file.

There's not a file. A `TXT` record is a certain type of response to a DNS query, just like an `A` record provides an IP address for a name, or a `CNAME` record provides an alias. You can't change it on your mail server — you need to update the records associated with your domain name.

> My
>   originaldomain.com is running in a
>   hosted server, where i dont have
>   terminal access.

You don't need terminal access. You need to talk to the company that hosts your DNS service. This is *probably* the site that you registered "originaldomain.com" with. (Note, though, that that's actually a real domain that belongs to someone. Use **example.com** for examples.) It may be your a web hosting provider or someone else, though. (It's rare for small or even moderate-sized organizations to run their own DNS servers these days.)

So, you need to look in the web interface those people provide you, and if there's no obvious way to set a TXT record, you should contact their tech support. And if they can't help you, you should strongly consider moving your domain name to a better service.

Comment: I have access i tried this "example.com. 3600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr a:out.example.com ~all" and then i tried a test email, i get all softfail "check-auth@verifier.port25.com"

Comment: example.com is the main domain name, there i have web access to change the TXT settings zone files. And out.example.com is the A record server i am testing now, from that we are trying to setup our newsletter.

Comment: I am using gandi.net to manage my DNS, do they have PTR and DKIM support ? Or i have to move then. thank you

Comment: I added this lines, is this ok ? @ 3600 IN TXT v=spf1 a mx ptr a:out.example.com ~all 
mail 3600 IN TXT v=spf1 a -all 
@ 3600 IN TXT ptr out.example.com. 
@ 3600 IN TXT ptr www.example.com.

Comment: In this site i am testing but still says SPF not found.  http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/